Where and how did Syluné die?
I'm reading through the Shadowdale: the Scouring of the Land adventure module for D&D 3.5e and I found some inconsistencies about Syluné's fate.
The spoilers below are integral to the events of the module. They are mostly background information locked behing high DC Knowledge checks or things you learn about quite early in the adventure.
We learn on page 13 under "Creature" that...

 ...Syluné died in 1356 DR by breaking a Staff of the Magi in order to defeat three large dragons that were attacking the village of Shadowdale. She fought atop the Tower of Ashaba (NE of the bridge over the Ashaba river), which the dragons were tearing apart to get her. Elminster used the bones of the three dragons to rebuild the damaged part of the tower. Esvele Greycloak raised those bones as a skeleton, which is said to be Gormauthator.


 So, both Gormauthator and Syluné died because of the staff, at the Tower of Ashaba.

But, on page 146 under Mistledale Mount, we learn that...

 ...at the base of the mount (SW of the bridge over the Ashaba river) a burned area marks the place where Gormauthator killed Syluné.


 So, Gormauthator killed Syluné across the road and the river from the Tower of Ashaba.

Are there novels or other official material that confirm one of these two versions?

Both Syluné and the dragon died when she broke the staff, near Mistledale Mount.
From the novel Azure Bonds (1988), p.164-167:

Sylune's hut was atop a low rise overlooking the road and the river Ashaba.

They go to the ruins of the hut, where they are told this story:

"She died battling a dragon," the old man explained. "A flight of 'em descended on the region a couple winters back. They destroyed a bunch a' towns. One of 'em took advantage of Elminster bein' out of the country. When this dragon attacked Shadowdale, Sylune was the only power around. She didn't stand a chance, but she had this staff."
Alias realized that the old man meant a magical staff, a staff of power.
"She broke it across the critter's nose, and everything went up in a pillar of flame—the dragon, the staff, and Sylune. It happened right across the way there." The old man pointed to the other side of the river.
By the moonlight. Alias' eyes could just pick out the naked, burned-out area of the woods. "Damn," she whispered softly.

The D&D 3e Shadowdale map archived here shows her hut east of the river, so they must be referring to the west of the river. Per the Central Shadowdale map, the Twisted Tower of Ashaba is on the same side of the river, so that couldn't be the location.
Of course, it may be that some of the fighting did take place in the Tower, even if the final blow took place in the forest. Syluné was a powerful mage, and may have used flight, teleportation, illusion, and so on, such that the fight took place across more than one location. It may even be that the old man was slightly misinformed, or that the map is in error.
